# Fail to using if/else to hover image by dynamic url

Tags: php, hover

I'm using the basic way to doing the hover image as the CSS method doesn't work for me. Current I'm using the if/else statement to do so. If the contain the URL like abc.com it will hover the image.

But now I only can hover the group url but if there is sub categories in groups I won't able to hover, how can I do it all the activity inside the group, the image will hover?

How to doing if the URL contain the words or path. For example abc.com/groups/* it will hover the groups. Similar like we doing searching in MySQL the words/variable as using "%".

```
<?php
 $request_url = apache_getenv("HTTP_HOST") . apache_getenv("REQUEST_URI");

 $e = 'abc.com/dev/';
 $f = 'abc.com/dev/groups/';
 $g = 'abc.com/dev/user/';  
?>

<div class="submenu">          
        <?php
        if ($request_url == $e) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_settings('home') . '"><div class="icon-home active"></div></a>';
        } else {
            echo '<a href = "' . get_settings('home') . '"><div class = "icon-home"></div></a>';
        }
        ?>

        <?php
        if ($request_url == $f) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_settings('home') . '/groups/"><div class="icon-groups active"></div></a>';
        } else {
            echo '<a href = "' . get_settings('home') . '/groups/"><div class = "icon-groups"></div></a>';
        }
        ?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a javascript way to do so, with jQuery

```
$("a[href*='THE_URL_PATTERN_YOU_WANT_TO_MATCH']").children(".icon-home").addClass("active");
```

BTW, it is NOT a good idea to wrap a `div` into a `a` tag.

Comment: I try to using the method you give but it doesn't work for me. $("a href='abc.com/dev/").children(".icon-home").addClass("active");. If there is the sub categories under the icon-home like abc.com/dev/test will the icon hovered?

Comment: your code is not correct, try `$("a[href*='abc.com/dev/']").children(".icon-home").addClass("active");`

Comment: have you included `jQuery` in your project?

Comment: Yes I did include `jQuery` in my project.

Comment: is there any javascript error when executing this code? it might show in your browser's console